# Android.mk, include all cpp files

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to build an Android project using the ndk, but I have run into some troubles.

Here's the Android.mk file that works:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp, Screen.cpp, ScreenManager.cpp  
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Is there a way that allows me to specify all the *.cpp files in the directory, without listing them manually under LOCAL_SRC_FILES?

So far I tried using LOCAL_SRC_FILES = $(wildcard *.cpp), but it did now work, it seems that no files get selected.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/[DIRECTORY]/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

... Change `[DIRECTORY]` to the actual directory of the files. If they are in the same directory as your `.mk` file then remove that part. Create the `FILE_LIST` variable to find all of the `.cpp` files under the `[DIRECTORY]` directory. Then use it in the file listing. The `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` line will then remove the `LOCAL_PATH` from the listing.

Comment: @DiscGolfer Why you remove `LOCAL_PATH` from the listing?

Comment: @Narek You must define `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)` at the top of your `Android.mk`. This holds the relative path from your NDK root to the current file. So, in the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` line above, I removed the `LOCAL_PATH` from the listing because the file paths are relative to `LOCAL_PATH`. Which would make the paths invalid if not removed.

Comment: What does the "wildcard" part mean?  Makes sense that LOCAL_PATH will get expanded into a path, is "wildard" a predefined value? Is something supposed to be substituted for "wildcard"?

Comment: @Alyoshak The wildcard keyword is a standard makefile function that matches and creates a list of filenames based on the pattern we give it. The only part you need to modify is the pattern being used (aka the path to your .cpp files)

Comment: What does $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) mean?

Comment: @Delargo This removes the `LOCAL_PATH` from each file path in the `FILE_LIST`. Itbasically makes the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` list contain only relative paths to your files.

Answer (score 22):

I've been using this script for my Android.mk saved me so much time!

```
#traverse all the directory and subdirectory
define walk
  $(wildcard $(1)) $(foreach e, $(wildcard $(1)/*), $(call walk, $(e)))
endef

#find all the file recursively under jni/
ALLFILES = $(call walk, $(LOCAL_PATH))
FILE_LIST := $(filter %.cpp, $(ALLFILES))

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/darkdukey/9402013c953ff57c73ba) is the gist

Comment: To anybody using this, make sure that this definition is placed in your Makefile _before_ any code that uses it, otherwise calls to it will silently fail.

Comment: just a note , this is the perfect solution

Comment: How exclude path from FILE_LIST? And why write $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%), not just $(FILE_LIST) when I assign FILE_LIST to LOCAL_SRC_FILES?

Answer (score 3):

How about like this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp))
```

If you'd be afraid that expansion of * contains $(LOCAL_PATH)/, it might be OK:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/./,,$(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/./*.cpp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $($(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp):$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```