# Android NDK makefile: Add recursive header search path

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm porting an iPhone game (c++) to Android and I'm just getting started with this.

Is there any way I can add a recursive header search path in the Android.mk file?
Because all the #includes in my code does not contain a path, just the file name between quotes. In Xcode this works perfectly but the ndk compiler can't find the headers.

Comment: A "recursive header search path"? The *compiler* can't find the headers? So there are some directories, and somewhere in those directories are subdirectories containing header files, and you want to construct a list of paths to those subdirectories in Make and pass it to the compiler, is that right?

Comment: @Beta yes, or whatever works, it can be a list of directories or maybe just a directory and tell the build system to search in subdirectories too, I don't know if that's possible, but that would be better so I don't have to update the makefile when I add a new directory.

Comment: So if we tell you how to construct the list, do you know how to pass it to the compiler? (I don't know ndk.)

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980284/android-mk-include-all-cpp-files