# Android NDK sources outside project

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my andoid.mk file I have to copy and paste my sources inside jni folder and do something like this:

```
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/myfolder/*.cpp)
```

How can I make it point to a path that is outside my project? Something like this:

```
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard /home/user/myfolder/folder/*.cpp)
```

Or make a variable and do it like this?

```
MY_VARIABLE = /home/user/mypath
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(MY_VARIABLE)/*.cpp)
```

Comment: Have a look at this issue. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980284/android-mk-include-all-cpp-files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980284/android-mk-include-all-cpp-files

Comment: That should be fine... the files don't have to be in the jni folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572821/ndk-how-to-reference-native-sources-outside-android-project/31573603#31573603