# NDK: How to reference native sources OUTSIDE Android project?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 and just downloaded 1.3RC3, as it reputedly has full NDK support.

I have a working project while my .c / .h files remain in `app/src/main/jni`; however, I want them in `AndroidProject/../common/src`, i.e. **outside the android project folder.** How do I make this work?

To reiterate: this question is about **EXTERNAL, NATIVE CODE**; not importing external java!

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096819/jni-and-gradle-in-android-studio, it seems like you could use that approach to specify where your native sources are located (I haven't tried this myself, as I'm still using Eclipse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was so simple, I didn't think to even try it at first, but it worked at once:

```
android{
   ...
   sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = ['../../common/test']
   ...
}
```

...which implies that the path is relative to `AndroidProject/app`.

A problem with this solution is that it is incompatible with a standalone `Android.mk`, since preventing `Android.mk` generation by gradle requires `sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []`.

Comment: Consider updating your answer to link to [Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental), that way it has less change to get outdated as they update the DSL.