# Android NDK - No such file or directory compilation terminated - Header files export issue

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, header-files, android.mk

I am trying to import the TagLib C++ library (http://taglib.github.io/) to Android using the NDK.

I was able to successfully compile the library by putting all the source code under `/jni/taglibroot/` as per picture bellow:

[image]

and running `ndk-build` on the `/jni` folder.

However, I have also created the `tag_lib_personal.cpp` file bellow (to use the TagLib API):

```
#include <jni.h>
/*#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>*/
#include <stdio.h>

#include <taglibroot/taglib/fileref.h>
#include <taglibroot/taglib/tag.h>
#include <taglibroot/taglib/tpropertymap.h>


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    jstring Java_com_mindtherobot_samples_ndkfoo_NdkFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {

      TagLib::FileRef f(argv[i]);

      if(!f.isNull() && f.audioProperties()) {

        TagLib::AudioProperties *properties = f.audioProperties();

        int seconds = properties->length() % 60;
        int minutes = (properties->length() - seconds) / 60;

        /*cout << "-- AUDIO --" << endl;
        cout << "bitrate     - " << properties->bitrate() << endl;
        cout << "sample rate - " << properties->sampleRate() << endl;
        cout << "channels    - " << properties->channels() << endl;
        cout << "length      - " << minutes << ":" << formatSeconds(seconds) << endl;*/
      }

      return "hello world!";

      //return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

But I cannot get it to compile. When I try to run `ndk-build` again I get the following error:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : my_own_source_files <= tag_lib_personal.cpp
In file included from D:/blabla/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64/workspace/Project//jni/tag_lib_personal.cpp:7:0:
D:/blabla/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64/workspace/Project//jni/taglibroot/taglib/fileref.h:29:19: fatal error: tfile.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [D:/blabla/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64/workspace/Project//obj/local/armeabi/objs/my_own_source_files/tag_lib_personal.o] Error 1
```

The error shows it cannot find some .h files from the TagLib library. Here is my `Android.mk` file though:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := taglib_module
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/*.cpp) #Based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8980441
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)


LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DFOO=1
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
# If I run ndk-build only on the above code, it compiles the TagLib library successfully and generates the .so files as expected


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := my_own_source_files
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := taglib_module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tag_lib_personal.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ape,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/asf,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/flac,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/it,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mod,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mp4,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpc,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg/id3v1,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg/id3v2,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg/id3v2/frames,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/flac,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/opus,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/speex,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/vorbis,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/riff,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/riff/aiff,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/riff/wav,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/s3m,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/toolkit,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/trueaudio,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/wavpack,\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/xm

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

As you can see I put every single directory of the TagLib library that has at least one .h file in the `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` directive but it for some reason still cannot find `tfile.h` (which is inside `$(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/toolkit`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing, you have an extra ;-)

Syntax for `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` does not expect these commas. You simply list all directories. Actually, you can use `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` instead (your post hints that you probably tried):

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ape\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/asf\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/flac\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/it\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mod\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mp4\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpc\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg/id3v1\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg/id3v2\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/mpeg/id3v2/frames\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/flac\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/opus\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/speex\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/ogg/vorbis\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/riff\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/riff/aiff\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/riff/wav\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/s3m\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/toolkit\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/trueaudio\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/wavpack\
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib/xm
```

**Note** If you encounter strange issues with `ndk-build` in the future, first advice is to run `ndk-build V=1`: it will log all actual compilation commands used by `ndk-build`, which may often expose the errors or typos in various `Android.mk` files.

**PS** Your build will finally fail. When you build taglib, you need also to compile all **.cpp** files in `taglibroot` subdirectories! I suggest that you try to build the library the way it was designed to be built, with **CMake**. The Android patches can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/android-cmake.

You can also try a straightforward approach, but I am not sure it will work:

```
MY_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := taglib_module
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)/taglibroot/taglib
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/ape\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/asf\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/flac\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/it\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/mod\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/mp4\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/mpc\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/mpeg\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/mpeg/id3v1\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/mpeg/id3v2\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/mpeg/id3v2/frames\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/ogg\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/ogg/flac\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/ogg/opus\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/ogg/speex\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/ogg/vorbis\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/riff\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/riff/aiff\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/riff/wav\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/s3m\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/toolkit\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/trueaudio\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/wavpack\
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/xm

FILE_LIST := $(foreach dir, $(LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DFOO=1
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE := my_own_shared_lib
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := taglib_module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tag_lib_personal.cpp

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please note that in your Java, you will load the two libraries, and order is important:

```
Runtime.loadLibrary("taglib_module");
Runtime.loadLibrary("my_own_shared_lib");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Alex. I tried your straightforward approach but it did not work. I guess I will have to study that cmake Android link you sent. I will do it and try again later. If you have any more ideas, please, let me know! :)

Comment: @Tiago: Hi Tiago, please let me know if this solution is working because i'm also getting same issue ? Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK This did not work for me. I gave up trying to add taglib to my Android project and went to another lib instead.